# Falha na instanciação de objetos: apenas o primeiro é criado

Tags: java, socket

Tenho uma classe em JAVA que é um Servidor. Eu pus nesta classe servidor o argumento porta, por exemplo.

Se eu for chamar esta classe eu faria assim: `new Servidor(5000);`.

*5000* é o argumento desta classe servidor, então eu criei uma nova classe frame com um botão, e na ação deste botão eu chamo esta classe servidor 5 vezes, mas com os argumentos diferentes e ficou assim :

```java
private void botaoIniciaServidoresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      

        Servidor servidor = new Servidor(5000);
        Servidor servidor1 = new Servidor(5001);
        Servidor servidor2 = new Servidor(5002);
        Servidor servidor3 = new Servidor(5003);
        Servidor servidor4 = new Servidor(5004);
}
```

Mas o problema é que quando eu clico no botão, o único servidor que inicia é o primeiro na porta 5000, eu já fiz o debug aqui e observei que somente a primeira instrução é executada, as outras 4 não são. Por quê isso?

Eu já tentei fazer assim:

```java
private void botaoIniciaServidoresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      

        new Servidor(5000);
        new Servidor(5001);
        new Servidor(5002);
        new Servidor(5003);
        new Servidor(5004);
}
```

Mesmo assim não dá certo, eu fiz o debug nos dois casos e somente o servidor da porta 5000 é iniciado.

---

## Atualização

O construtor da classe `Servidor`:

```java
public Servidor(int porta) {

    try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
    System.out.println("Servidor "+ porta + " Online ");

    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);

    while (true) {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();

        new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();
    }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

---

## Atualização 2

Vou postar o código, somente para adicionar, eu não tenho problema nenhum com o servidor, ele roda perfeitamente. Só tenho problema para chamar 2 ou mais servidores de outra classe frame com um botão, pois quero iniciar aqui e rodas uns 100 servidores em portas diferentes, e como está eu preciso ficar de um por um alterando a porta e iniciando. Já imaginaram? Eu debuguei e observer que o NetBeans só executa um servidor e os outros não.

Segue o código:

```java
package Pacote;

import Pacote.Mensageiro.Acao;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class Servidor {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapOnline = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();
    public int porta;

    // nova lista para armazenar todas as janelas ativas
    private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapJanelaLista = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();
    Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
    int horas = data.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutos = data.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int segundos = data.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    public Servidor(int porta) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
            System.out.println("Servidor "+ porta + " Online ");

            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);

            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    private class ListenerSocket implements Runnable {

        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private ObjectInputStream input;

        public ListenerSocket(Socket socket) {
            try {
                this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                this.input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }

        public void run() {
            Mensageiro message = null;
            try {
                while ((message = (Mensageiro) input.readObject()) != null) {
                    Acao action = message.getAcao();

                    if (action.equals(Acao.CONNECT)) {
                        boolean isConnect = conectar(message, output);
                        if (isConnect) {
                            mapOnline.put(message.getNome(), output);
                            enviarOnline();
                            enviarJanelaLista();
                            System.out.println(message.getNome() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + " Entrou ");
                        }
                    } else if (action.equals(Acao.DISCONNECT)) {
                        desconectar(message, output);
                        enviarOnline();
                        enviarJanelaLista();

                        return;
                    } else if (action.equals(Acao.SEND_ONE)) {
                        enviarUm(message);
                    } else if (action.equals(Acao.SEND_ALL)) {
                        enviarTodos(message);
                    } else if (action.equals(Acao.DISCONNECT_JANELA_LISTA)) { // faz a conexao para a janela da lista
                        // remove a janela da lista
                        mapJanelaLista.remove(message.getNome());
                        // formamos o fim do while (da thread referente) para esta janela
                        message = null;
                    } else if (action.equals(Acao.CONNECT_JANELA_LISTA)) { // desconecta a janela da lista

                        //adiciona a janela na lista
                        mapJanelaLista.put(message.getNome(), output);
                        enviarJanelaLista();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                desconectar(message, output);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean conectar(Mensageiro message, ObjectOutputStream output) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
            if (kv.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(message.getNome())) {
                message.setText("NO");
                enviar(message, output);
                return false;
            }

        }

        if (mapOnline.size() == 0) {
            message.setText("YES");
            enviar(message, output);
            return true;
        } else {
            message.setText("YES");
            enviar(message, output);
            return true;
        }

        // return false;
    }

    private void desconectar(Mensageiro message, ObjectOutputStream output) {
        // como temos agora 2 tipos de mensagem, do chat e da janela, precisamos fazer uns testes extras
        if (message != null) {
            // vamos aqui retirar um cliente do chat
            if (mapOnline.containsKey(message.getNome())) {
                mapOnline.remove(message.getNome());
                enviarOnline();
                enviarJanelaLista();
            }

            // vamos aqui retirar um janela de lista
            if (mapJanelaLista.containsKey(message.getNome())) {
                mapJanelaLista.remove(message.getNome());
            }
            System.out.println(message.getNome() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + " Saiu ");
        }
    }

    private void enviar(Mensageiro message, ObjectOutputStream output) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void enviarUm(Mensageiro message) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
            if (kv.getKey().equals(message.getNomeReservado())) {
                try {
                    kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void enviarTodos(Mensageiro message) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
            if (!kv.getKey().equals(message.getNome())) {
                message.setAcao(Acao.SEND_ONE);
                try {
                    kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void enviarOnline() {
        Set<String> setNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
            setNames.add(kv.getKey());
        }

        Mensageiro message = new Mensageiro();
        message.setAcao(Acao.USERS_ONLINE);
        message.setSetOnline(setNames);

        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
            message.setNome(kv.getKey());
            try {
                kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    // esse metodo atualiza a lista de clientes ativos no chat para as janelas da lista que estão abertas
    private void enviarJanelaLista() {
        Set<String> setNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
            setNames.add(kv.getKey());
        }

        Mensageiro message = new Mensageiro();
        message.setAcao(Acao.USERS_ONLINE);
        message.setSetOnline(setNames);

        for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapJanelaLista.entrySet()) {
            message.setNome(kv.getKey());
            try {
                kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Ramon, tem como adicionar o código fonte da classe Servidor?

Comment: Possivelmente o problema está na classe servidor.

Comment: Coloque o código interno da sua classe!

Comment: Continuando no mesmo registo do resto das pessoas, mostre o código da classe Servidor. Tenha em conta que se dentro de `Servidor` existir uma chamada sincrona que bloqueie a execução, os restantes servidores não serão executados.

Comment: está muito ruim o título da sua pergunta, sugiro reformular

Comment: @utluiz Sugestão de título que pode ajudar pessoas com problemas parecidos: _Como instanciar múltiplos servidores - somente o primeiro é iniciado_

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema está nesta chamada:

```
while (true) {
socket = serverSocket.accept();
new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();
}
```

Não só `serverSocket.accept()` é uma chamada síncrona, como não existe uma condição de saída para o ciclo `while`. Da forma como está, o primeiro servidor instanciado vai correr sem nunca sair.

Pode optar por mudar para:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();
```

Desta forma, o servidor vai esperar por uma ligação e quando a receber vai permitir que os outros servidores sejam instanciados (da mesma forma que este, i.e, vão esperar pela primeira ligação).

Ou então pode iniciar cada servidor na sua própria thread.

```
new Thread(new Servidor(5000));
new Thread(new Servidor(5001));
...
```

Comment: Legal ! é só retirar o while correto ? Vou tentar !

Comment: @RamomMoura certo. Tenha so em atenção que da forma que está, vai continuar a bloquear, enquanto não receber a primeira ligação.

Comment: Bom dia meu amigo, fiz o teste aqui e parece ainda executa somente o primeiro server, eu ainda observo que tem um outro while e fica no método run() o que você acha ? Abraço irmão

Comment: @RamomMoura pelo código que apresenta, apesar de ter um `while` no `run`, a execução da thread principal não deverá ficar presa ai, dado que `new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();` vai correr o método `run` numa nova `thread`. Tem a certeza que o servidor recebeu uma nova ligação e não está ainda preso no `socket = serverSocket.accept();` ?

Comment: Sim sim ! Retirei o While e fiz aqui de novo agora ! E eu Debugo linha a linha para ter certeza, tentei chamar de duas formas, a primeira :

      Servidor server1 = new Servidor(5000);   
      Servidor server2 =  new Servidor(5001);
      ....

E da sugunda

new Servidor(5000);
new Servidor(5001);

Mas está brabo, tem algo ainda segurando. Muito obrigado pela força, bom dia.

Comment: @RamomMoura um detalhe, a única diferença entre 'Servidor server1 = new Servidor(...)' ou 'new Servidor(...)' é que na segunda forma perde a referência para o servidor que criou, o que impossibilita manipula-lo posteriormente. Posto isto não irá afectar qual das formas use. Coloque os breakpoints em cada servidor. Só atinge o primeiro breakpoint? Coloque o breakpoint depois de `new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();` e veja se esse código é atingido. Não seria má ideia actualizar a pergunta com o novo código do servidor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15028/discussion-between-omni-and-ramom-moura).